# ¿Posible herencia entre propiedades del mismo nombre pero de distinto tipo?

Tags: c#, .net, poo

Estoy implementando un cliente de un servicio que me provee de ciertas clases a través de un WSDL.
En sí estas clases arman una estructura un poco compleja, pero conectándome a 2 métodos del servicio las respuestas son casi idénticas en cuanto a objetos, con la diferencia que por alguna razón las clases tienen distinto nombre. Poniendo un ejemplo:

```
partial class PelotasServicio1 : object{
    List<Pelota1> pelotas;
}
partial class Pelota1 : object {
    string color;
    float diametro;
}
partial class PelotasServicio2 : object {
    List<Pelota2> pelotas;
}
partial class Pelota2 : object {
    string color;
    float diametro;
}
```

Lo que desearía hacer es una clase, que por ejemplo, se conecte a cualquiera de los 2 servicios, y calcule la suma de los volúmenes de las pelotas que se recibió como respuesta. (Importante: no puedo modificar las clases proxy generadas por el WSDL ya que se actualizan constantemente)
Aún no sé como implementar la arquitectura siguiendo SOLID/DRY/KISS para no complicar los modelos.
Lo que se me ocurrió es hacer por ejemplo una clase Pelota o Esfera que implemente `CalcularVolumen()` con el diámetro que posee, pero no sé como hacer encajar esto con las otras clases. Podría hacer una clase que contenga un método `CalcularVolumen(int radio)` y ya, pero el problema que tengo en la realidad es que la estructura tiene mucha complejidad.

La pregunta es: *¿Cómo puedo hacer para que la respuesta de ambos métodos del servicio (con posibilidad de agregar mas métodos) puedan realizar el mismo cálculo sin repetir código?* En lo posible una solución genérica porque se me presentaron muchos de estos casos y el código está repetido.
Muchas gracias

Update 1:
No puedo modificar las clases que mostré, son autogeneradas. Ejemplo de código duplicado que quiero evitar:

```
// Suma los volúmenes de las pelotas del servicio 1
public double ConsumirServicio1() {
    PelotasServicio1 servicio1Response = _ws.GetServicio1();
    double suma = 0;
    foreach (Pelota1 pelota in servicio1Response.pelotas) {
        suma += (3/4)*Math.PI*Math.Pow((pelota.diametro / 2), 3);
    }
    return suma;
}

// Suma los volúmenes de las pelotas del servicio 2
public double ConsumirServicio2() {
    PelotasServicio2 servicio2Response = _ws.GetServicio2();
    double suma = 0;
    foreach (Pelota2 pelota in servicio2Response.pelotas) {
        suma += (3/4)*Math.PI*Math.Pow((pelota.diametro / 2), 3);
    }
    return suma;
}
```

Comment: Hola @sstan gracias por preguntar. Las clases de arriba son autogeneradas sin posibilidad de modificarlas. Sólo puedo usarlas pero quiero hacer una abstracción para extenderlas de alguna manera y no duplicar código. Hablando de extender se me vino a la cabeza Extension Methods pero no sé si servirá. Puse un código de ejemplo que es mas o menos parecido a lo que tengo que hacer.

Comment: Tampoco puedes agregarle una interfaz? con una interfaz (que no afecta en si a la clase), podrías crear un método de extensión que pueda calcular el dato. No se si agregarlo como respuesta pues no se si te afecta el agregar la interfaz.

Comment: @Luis si puedo agregar interfaz, pero lo malo es que no puedo tocar las clases por lo que no podría hacer que implementen dicha "interface". Con la solución de la respuesta de abajo me funcionó perfecto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema fundamental es que tu sabes una cosa que el compilador desconoce: que tanto la clase `Pelota1` como la clase `Pelota2` tienen un campo idéntico `float diametro`.

La solución habitual para transmitirle esa información al compilador, de forma que éste te permitiese usar las dos clases indistintamente, sería hacer que ambas implementasen una interfaz con un campo así, y usar dicha interfaz en el método de cálculo de volumen.

El problema es que no puedes modificar las clases, asi que no puedes hacer que implementen esa interfaz (además de que una interfaz no puede contener campos, sólo propiedades). Pero existe otra solución: usar el tipo `dynamic`, introducido en .NET Framework 4:

```
// Suma los volúmenes de las pelotas del servicio 1
public double ConsumirServicio1()
{
    PelotasServicio1 servicio1Response = _ws.GetServicio1();
    return CalcularVolumenPelotas(servicio1Response.pelotas);

}

// Suma los volúmenes de las pelotas del servicio 2
public double ConsumirServicio2()
{
    PelotasServicio2 servicio2Response = _ws.GetServicio2();
    return CalcularVolumenPelotas(servicio2Response.pelotas);
}

private double CalcularVolumenPelotas(IEnumerable<dynamic> pelotas)
{
    double suma = 0;
    foreach (dynamic pelota in pelotas)
    {
        suma += (3.0 / 4) * Math.PI * Math.Pow((pelota.diametro / 2), 3);
    }
    return suma;
}
```

Con esto puedes usar cualquier clase que tenga un campo `diametro`. A esta técnica se le llama [duck typing](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

Para acabar, ten cuidado, hay un error en tu fórmula de cálculo del volumen. Cuando pones `(3/4)` estás realizando una división de enteros, cuyo resultado en C# es siempre un entero redondeado hacia abajo. En este caso sería 0, por lo que tu volumen calculado siempre será 0. Para evitar esto basta con usar en su lugar `(3.0/4)`, ya que al utilizar un `double`, el resultado es correctamente un double (0.75).

Comment: Buena idea, no se me había ocurrido. Obviamente, se pierde la protección que brinda el compilador de verificar que de verdad existe el campo `diametro`, pero esto me parece la mejor alternativa según lo que pide OP.

Comment: Gracias @Gua-naiko-che esa es la solución que encontré anoche, me leiste la mente, lo probé y si funciona.